# java operator + not defined for type(s) Integer, int

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to implement a shopping cart and I have some problems with the Integer class. This is the code:

```
public class ShoppingCart<Product, Integer> extends TreeMap<Product, Integer> {

void addToCart(Product product) {
    if (this.containsKey(product)) {
        Integer nrOfProds = this.get(product);
        this.put(product, nrOfProds + 1); //the problem is here
    } else
        this.put(product, Integer.valueOf(1)); //and also here
}
....
}
```

Eclipse says "operator + undefined for type(s) Integer, int". But I read about unboxing, and I thought I would be ok.

Never mind, I tried to work this around, so I tried calling intValue() on nrOfProds. This time, Eclipse said "method intValue() is undefined for type Integer". How come? It is defined for type Integer.

There`s also a problem with with Integer.valueOf(1). It`s undefined method, again.

What is wrong with this?

Comment: You should not extend TreeMap. You should *use* it inside your own class. Otherwise, anybody will be able to call `shoppingCart.put(product, 67)` and bypass your `addToCart()` method.

Comment: Are you sure you want your ShoppingCart class to extend TreeMap? Although you have an addToCart method, all the methods of TreeMap are still public, and can be called directly to override the invariants of your class (inserting values that don't make sense). Likely it would be better for your map to be an ordinary (private) field of the ShoppingCart class. You can add methods to ShoppingCart which defer to the map as needed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have declared `Integer` as type parameter of your class, which overrides the `java.lang.Integer` class. The values you give after the class name in angular brackets while declaring it are type parameters.

Change the class declaration to:

```
public class ShoppingCart extends TreeMap<Product, Integer>
```

Ideally, you should avoid extending the `TreeMap`. Rather have it as an `instance` field in my class.

Comment: @Hame Sure. Also, you should consider having the `TreeMap<Product, Integer>` as a field, rather than extending it.

Comment: I have considered your indication and used the TreeMap inside the ShoppingCart class

Comment: @Hame. That's nice. It would be easier and also the correct way to work with. :)

Comment: Yes, now I think the same way. I don`t have enough experience yet, to take into consideration all these factors. Also, the comments from the guys above were very useful.